# Is there any way to reduce expo apk size without using pure react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to install pure react-native but every now and then I am getting some error. So it would be nice if there is a way to reduce expo apk size.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate to react-native

- make a new react app "react-native init"
- Copy the source files over from Expo project
- Install all dependencies of the Expo project except Expo specific
  libraries.
- Make necessary adjustments to app.json file
- Download the signing key of your Android app from Expo using exp
- fetch:android:keystore and set it up

More details here [Reduced the Size of React Native App by 86%](https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640)

Comment: Will this reduce expo apk to pure react-native apk size ??

Comment: @KUMARSAURAV It must be

Comment: I think you have written something wrong, you have written exp instead of expo